# How to download canvas content as a svg(.svg extension) image/file in angular 6 and above

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some canvas graphs(used chart.js to draw graphs) in UI and i want to download graph as svg image/file in angular 6 and above.

I have gone through many sites, almost took half a day but did not get any solution for this and even i tried html2canvas to save as svg file but it did not support. some where i heard as d3.js and some other libraries have the capacity to draw svg, but i want to save as a svg file and please go through my below code, any answer would be appreciated.

.html:->

```
   <div>
      <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData" id="myCanvas" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [colors]="pieChartColors"
        [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
        [legend]="pieChartLegend">
      </canvas>
    </div>
<div>
  <button (click)="svg_method()">DOWNLOAD</button>
</div>
```

.ts:->

```
svg_method(){
      console.log("downloading functionality");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var theImg    = theCanvas.toDataURL("image/svg");
```

Comment: yes i have tried, it wont support as already i mentioned. i can download but content will be empty.

Comment: If you log the content `console.log(theImg)` is it empty?

Comment: This isn't going to work: obviously, it will be empty. An SVG is not like a png or a jpeg.  For comparison, assume that instead of SVG, you wanted HTML: `theCanvas.toDataURL("text/html");`. That's effectively the same end result as `image/svg`. Canvas to SVG can be done, but to extract it, the canvas generally has to be set up properly in a very specific way (there are libraries that do this)

Comment: then how can i achieve this, any special method @DanCouper

Comment: They're drastically different things. You find or write something that maps the path drawing commands in canvas to similar ones used to create SVG elements. SVG creation can be done the same way as creating HTML elements, so if you can map those commands to the creation of elements you can get a basic result. There are some libraries that will help (google, there are _many_ other SO answers): note that none seem to have been updated for a long long time.

Comment: Didn't knew that. I thought they support the svg extension by default, because they don't list any on MDN site.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that an SVG isn't like (for example) a JPEG or PNG. It's a markup language, written as a text file with instructions defined in XML. The SVG itself isn't really an image, it's a set of instructions to an engine that understands SVG to draw an image. The *support* is fine, but it's just that it can't just be trivially converted to.

Answer (score 0):

So canvas operates with raster graphics and the charts.js leverages exactly that. So what you are getting is bitmap graphics out of it.

Canvas allows you to easily extract image data as raster graphics, but not easily as vector graphics as to do so there needs to be a mechanism to run through image's pixel space, trace contours etc and eventually create SVG markup.

Specifically for your use case someone wrote this library:
https://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/

Give it a try.

Other alternative would be to use potrace.js or similar libraries, but I think it can be a rabbit hole for your use case.